# jQuery how to add another css in code?

Tags: jquery, css

Hi i have this code right now on my website...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var scrollSpeed = 50;       // Speed in milliseconds
        var step = 1;               // How many pixels to move per step
        var current = 0;            // The current pixel row
        var imageWidth = 4000;      // Background image width
        var headerWidth = screen.width;     // How wide the header is.

        //The pixel row where to start a new loop
        var restartPosition = -(imageWidth - headerWidth);

        function scrollBg(){
            //Go to next pixel row.
            current -= step;

            //If at the end of the image, then go to the top.
            if (current == restartPosition){
                current = 0;
            }

            //Set the CSS of the header.
            $('#body').css("background-position",current+"px 0");
        }

        //Calls the scrolling function repeatedly
        var init = setInterval("scrollBg()", scrollSpeed);
</script>
```

I'm trying to add a second jQuery selector to:

```
$('#body').css("background-position",current+"px 0");
```

so that the css background-position property is changed for two elements.

IE 8 will not work with gradient and background so I'm using a nested div (class="flash-bg") with the background picture and want to update it's background-position so that it will animate in IE as well.

How can I add "flash-bg" to the jquery code? Is there a way to just add it next to '#body'? Or just repeat the code except with '#flash-bg'? Thanks!

Comment: Did you assign id to document body?

Comment: Actually all i had to do was change the '#body' to '.flash-bg' then it works both in IE and other browsers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set the `background-position` on both `#body` and `.flash-bg`, this will work:

```
$('#body, .flash-bg').css("background-position",current+"px 0");
```

Also, in your `setInterval`, you can pass a reference to the function instead of a string to be `eval`:ed:

```
var init = setInterval(scrollBg, scrollSpeed);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! just what i needed. and thank you for the bonus, seems be to executing a lot smoother :D

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you simply want to add the `flash-bg` class if the browser is IE. You can do something like this, using IE's [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#body').addClass("flash-bg");
    });
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks i'll keep this at hand!

Comment: where would i put this conditional comment? inside the jquery itself?

Comment: No, you would put this in your html, after your other jQuery script.

Comment: hmm this didn't work I put in another " after flash-bg and tried ".flash-bg" but does not work :C

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#body, div.flash-bg').css("background-position",current+"px 0");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for addClass http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

```
$('#body').addClass('flash-bg');
```